# Derive a running total from a calculated value

Tags: sql, mysql

Fairly new to SQL (started Monday) and unfortunately I think the problem I've started with is a complicated one.

I've a dataset that looks like this:

```
mysql> select * from clouddata;
```

| jobId | CloudPlatform | TimeOccurred | NodeIdentifier | tags | Action | HardwareType | HardwareUnitCost | ResourceCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AWS | 2023-11-13 01:00:00 | Cluster-1 | NULL | start | MC5 | 1.23 | 5 |
| 2 | AWS | 2023-11-13 02:00:00 | Cluster-2 | NULL | start | MC4 | 2.76 | 3 |
| 3 | AWS | 2023-11-13 03:00:00 | Cluster-1 | NULL | start | MC5 | 1.23 | 2 |
| 4 | AWS | 2023-11-13 04:00:00 | Cluster-2 | NULL | stop | MC4 | 2.76 | 3 |
| 5 | AWS | 2023-11-13 05:00:00 | Cluster-1 | NULL | stop | MC5 | 1.23 | 5 |
| 6 | AWS | 2023-11-13 06:00:00 | Cluster-1 | NULL | stop | MC5 | 1.23 | 2 |

I'm trying to calculate a running cost total from a cluster activity log stored in a MySQL 8.0.35 database (but could be SQL Server) and hitting a few issues.

I have event data extracted from a cloud log that represents clusters over a period of time.  Events are either addition or removal of nodes from a cluster, which change the cost-per-second rate.

I'd like to capture the overall running total.  The costs are calculated as:

```
if Action == start, cost = ResourceCount * HardwareUnitCost * time difference between this row and the previous row

if Action == stop, cost = ResourceCount * HardwareUnitCost * time difference between this row and the previous row * -1
```

This should give a "spend rate", which can be added to the spend rate of the previous row, which can then be used to calculate the cost.

I came up with this for the spend rate within a row:

```sql
select
    sum(
        if(
            strcmp(Action, "start"),
            HardwareUnitCost * ResourceCount * TIMESTAMPDIFF(
                SECOND,
                timeOccurred,
(
                    LEAD(timeOccurred, 1, 0) OVER (
                        order by
                            TimeOccurred
                    )
                )
            ) * -1,
            HardwareUnitCost * ResourceCount * TIMESTAMPDIFF(
                SECOND,
                timeoccurred,
(
                    LEAD(timeOccurred, 1, 0) OVER (
                        order by
                            T imeOccurred
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ) as spend_rate
from
    clouddata;
```

But this gives:

> ERROR 3593 (HY000): You cannot use the window function 'lead' in this context.'

Stripping out the sum() gives the right numbers:

| spend_rate |
| --- |
| 22140.00 |
| 29808.00 |
| 8856.00 |
| -29808.00 |
| -22140.00 |
| NULL |

There's lots of running total how-tos out there but they mostly focus on SUM, which I don't believe I can use as I'm calculating the components dynamically.

Comment: You can't have nested window functions or aggregate functions calling window functions. If you create a subquery with the LAG parts and summarize it out the outside, it should work.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), especially #5 and #3.

Comment: It will be more clear, if you want calculate timediff between event ``023-11-13 01:00:00 Cluster-1 start MC5`` and event ``2023-11-13 05:00:00 Cluster-1 stop MC5``. Then total time spent is 04:00:00. You can use ``partition by NodeIdentifier, HardwareType``. But, in this case, test data is incomplete or contradictory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Try something like this If I understand your requirements:

```
SELECT IDENTITY (int,1,1) as MYID,
        TimeOccurred,Action,    
        CASE
            WHEN Action = 'Start' THEN (HardwareUnitCost*ResourceCount)
            ELSE (HardwareUnitCost*ResourceCount*-1)
        END AS 'Cost'
        ,0 As 'SpendRate'
        ,0 As 'TotalSpendRate'
INTO CoudData
FROM #temp_job_data
ORDER BY TimeOccurred

declare @Cost INT = 0
declare @SpendRate INT = 0
declare @PreviousTime DateTime = NULL
declare @CurrentTime DateTime = NULL
declare @MyID INT = 0

set @MyID = (select MIN (MyID) from #TempCoudData)

WHILE EXISTS (Select 1 from #TempCoudData where MyID=@MyID)
BEGIN
    --Check if is the first row we will not have a previous time
    IF @PreviousTime IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @PreviousTime = (select TimeOccurred from #TempCoudData where MyID=@MyID)
        SET @Cost = (select Cost from #TempCoudData where MyID=@MyID)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @CurrentTime = (select TimeOccurred from #TempCoudData where MyID=@MyID)
        SET @Cost = @Cost * DATEDIFF(SECOND, @PreviousTime, @CurrentTime)
        SET @SpendRate = @SpendRate + @Cost
        SET @MyID = @MyID-1

        UPDATE #TempCoudData SET SpendRate = @Cost, TotalSpendRate= @SpendRate  WHERE MyID=@MyID

        SET @MyID = @MyID+1
        SET @PreviousTime = @CurrentTime
        SET @Cost = (select Cost from #TempCoudData where MyID=@MyID)
    END
    SET @MyID = @MyID+1
END

select * FROM #TempCoudData
DROP TABLE #TempCoudData
```

Comment: thanks @Gesuele Russello, I adapted your technique of using a temp table in MySQL (I think your syntax is for SQL Server), which I'll post when time permits